# Why cant i define global classes' member function inside main?

Tags: c++

**I know that it is not allowed and it doesnt work, i am seeking explanations.**
Also why am i not able to define the member functions using :: operator inside the main?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class c1{
    int i,j;
    public:
        int seti(int a);
        int setj(int b);

};



int main(){
//defining the function inside main

//Why both of them are invalid and dont compile
int ::c1::seti(int a){
    i=a;
}
int c1::setj(int b){
    j=b;
}


}
```

Comment: Because that's not how C++ is specified to work?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude is that the only reason??

Comment: What answer is going to satisfy you exactly? Why do you even *want* to write code like that?

Comment: While nested functions could be useful in some cases (and these days can be emulated with lambda expressions), defining *member* functions like that makes no sense really. The `c1` class scope is not inside the `main` function, why would you even want to define the member functions inside another function? Doing it like that will just make the code harder to read, understand and maintain.

Comment: Because the scope of  `class c1` is **global**, there is no sense at all to make its member function **local**.